# Is a descending index beneficial for SELECT..WHERE in the case when the value being located is near the maximum in the table?

Tags: indexing, firebird

Using: Firebird 2.5.3

This is something that I couldn't ascertain from the (current) Firebird docs regarding table indexes.

Table structure is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE CHILDTABLE 
(
  ROW_ID                  INTEGER         NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ID                 INTEGER         NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_CHILDTABLE  PRIMARY KEY (ROW_ID)
);
```

A query that will select 1 or more rows from this table looks like this:

```
SELECT ROW_ID FROM CHILDTABLE WHERE PARENT_ID = ?
```

Questions:

1. Given that every time this query is sent to the database, it will ask for a PARENT_ID value (the parameter) which is near the maximum of the set of values in the table (and also among its most recently added rows), will a descending index be preferred over an ascending one, for the purpose of retrieving the result quicker/faster from the database?
2. Given the scenario, is there any negative performance impact to use the descending index instead of an ascending index? (Eg. Would more processing need to be done by the server for every row inserted if it were a descending index instead of an ascending index, and how will indexes affect insert performance on the table as it grows in size?)

Answer (score 2):

> Questions:
>
> > Given that every time this query is sent to the database, it will ask for a PARENT_ID value (the parameter) which is near the maximum of
> >     the set of values in the table (and also among its most recently added
> >     rows), will a descending index be preferred over an ascending one, for
> >     the purpose of retrieving the result quicker/faster from the database?

No. An index consists of two data structures: a ordered list (implemented as singly linked list in Firebird) and a search tree (implemented as B-Tree).

It seems that you mental model of index access is that it uses the ordered list to find the matching row by just following the list starting from one end. However, in fact it uses a B-Tree traversal which can find any spot in the index with the same number of operations.

> > Given the scenario, is there any negative performance impact to use the descending index instead of an ascending index? (Eg. Would more processing need to be done by the server for every row inserted if it were a descending index instead of an ascending index, and how will indexes affect insert performance on the table as it grows in size?)

I don't think there is any noticeable difference. The reason for `DESC` indexes is to support `ORDER BY ... DESC`. That's the only reason to think about index ordering at all.

References:

- [How the B-Tree works](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree)
- [How indexes may help `ORDER BY`](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) 
  Note that Firebird is an exception to the rule described there: In Firebird, the index order must always exactly match the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Minor nitpick: indexes in Firebird are doubly linked, but the reverse link is considered unreliable and therefor not used for backward data scans, see http://ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_20

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I guess that is effectively the same :)

Comment: True. Lets hope they find a way to change that in the future (although that will probably open a new set of problems with the prefix-compression used in the index structure)